# How Can I Create A Simple PHP Mail Form For My Website?

Tags: php, html, mailto, mail-form

I already have a form set up on my site. I created the form code myself.

I started experiencing problems with having the information e-mailed to me, one day everything is fine and it gets e-mailed to me, the next day the confirmation message comes up but nothing gets sent to my e-mail.

This is very critical for my line of work.

My question is: How can I create a simple php mail form that will always work?

**This is the code I have now:**

```
    $('#rSubmit').click(function(validateform){        
      var data = {};
      data.to = "greatlimoservice@gmail.com";
      data.from = "greatlimoservice@greatlimoservice.com";
      data.subject = "New Reservation"; 
      data.message = "New Reservation from Website \n"+
                        '\n First Name      : '+$('#name').val()+
                        '\n Last Name       : '+$('#lastname').val() +
                        '\n Company Name    : '+$('#company').val() +
                        '\n Phone Number    : '+$('#phone').val() +
                        '\n Street Address  : '+$('#street').val() +
                        '\n Pick-Up City    : '+$('#city').val()+
                        '\n Pick-Up State   : '+$('#state').val() +
                        '\n Pick-Up Zip     : '+$('#zip').val() +
                        '\n Date            : '+$('#calendar').val()+
                        '\n Time            : '+$('#time').val() +
                        '\n Time            : '+$('#time2').val() +
                        '\n Time            : '+$('#time3').val() +
                        '\n Airport         : '+$('#airport').val() +
                        '\n Airline         : '+$('#airline').val() +
                        '\n Flight #        : '+$('#fnumber').val() +
                        '\n Stops           : '+$('#hstops').val() +
                        '\n Stops Info      : '+$('#info').val() +
                        '\n Passengers      : '+$('#passengers').val() +
                        '\n Luggages        : '+$('#luggages').val()+
                        '\n Car Seat        : '+$('#seat').val()+
                        '\n Drop-Off Street : '+$('#dostreet').val() +
                        '\n Drop-Off City   : '+$('#docity').val()+
                        '\n Drop-Off State  : '+$('#dostate').val() +
                        '\n Drop-Off Zip    : '+$('#dozip').val() +
                        '\n D.O Airport     : '+$('#doairport').val() +
                        '\n D.O Airline     : '+$('#doairline').val() +
                        '\n Flight #        : '+$('#dofnumber').val() +
                        '\n Date            : '+$('#calendar2').val()+
                        '\n Time            : '+$('#rtime').val() +
                        '\n Time            : '+$('#rtime2').val() +
                        '\n Time            : '+$('#rtime3').val() +
                        '\n Return Street   : '+$('#rtstreet').val() +
                        '\n Return City     : '+$('#rtcity').val()+
                        '\n Return State    : '+$('#rtstate').val() +
                        '\n Return Zip      : '+$('#rtzip').val() +                            
                        '\n Return Airport  : '+$('#rtairport').val() +
                        '\n Return Airline  : '+$('#rtairline').val() +
                        '\n Return Flight # : '+$('#rtfnumber').val() +                         
                        '\n Payment Type    : '+$('#payment').val() +
                        '\n Card Number     : '+$('#creditcardno').val() +
                        '\n Exp. Date       : '+$('#expirydate').val() +
                        '\n Exp. Date       : '+$('#expirydate2').val()

                    ;

alert("Congratulations! Your reservation has been made. Your confirmation number is 3851. Please contact us if you have any questions or comments.");




});
```

**Is there any other easier/convenient way or coding I can use that will work properly? I need to always get an e-mail once a person clicks "Submit" on my site and this coding isn't working for me**

Comment: *"one day everything is fine and it gets e-mailed to me, the next day the confirmation message comes up but nothing gets sent to my e-mail."* - **Q:** Did you modify anything since it did work, and did you keep a working copy of the one that was working?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you do not have a closing brace for `$('#rSubmit').click(function(){`

Comment: Try adding a brace to your `;` like this `};` see if that works. The one underneath `'\n Exp. Date : '+$('#expirydate2').val()`

Comment: Are you over your 50 email limit from Squaresend?

Comment: @Fred I did not modify anything since then since it was working fine

Comment: @user2654581 Did you try my suggestion/answer below? There is a missing closing brace for your `click(function(){` function.

Comment: @Fred yes I added it, thank you very much. I still did not get it e-mailed to me but I am still searching if the problem is with "squaresend"

Comment: @user2654581 Ok, I will modify my answer then and leave the forms related info in there if you want. I'll try and figure out the problem, hopefully. Maybe someone else will be able to pinpoint it. You can also use Ajax. I will find some info for you as well.

Comment: @Fred Thank you very much, I appreciate your help greatly. One more question, do you know any way I can have an echo message pop up once someone click the submit button?

Comment: @user2654581 I'm pretty sure you will be able to use most of your code in your JS to be used in conjunction with Ajax.

Comment: @user2654581 You're very much welcome. In regards to having a an echo message, is this for your existing JS form you have now or for a PHP form?

Comment: @Fred It's for my existing form

Comment: @user2654581 Your `alert("Congratulations!` is not taking care of that?

Comment: @Fred The alert is now working. I'm still trying to get the e-mail to be sent to me..

Comment: @user2654581 What is inside your `send2.php` file? Are you already using Ajax or just plain JS to pass the info on to `send2.php`?

Comment: @user2654581 Plus, from what I can tell by your source is that your `onsubmit="return validateForm()` function is going to an empty function `<script>function validateForm() { } </script>`

Comment: @user2654581 Try replacing this `$(document).ready(function() {` with `$(document).ready(function(validateForm) {` see if that will work. I'm not a JS expert, but it only makes sense that `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` is looking for a function called `validateForm` and is not finding it.

Comment: @Fred I changed it to [ $(document).ready(function(validateForm) { ]
It still did not work. I changed the scripting of my form just now

Comment: @user2654581 I wish I knew how to fix your present problem, but to be honest with you, I don't know how. Have you had a look at this yet? http://codular.com/php-jquery-contact-form

Comment: @user2654581 By the way, `validateForm` is not the same as `validateform` - notice the Uppercase F in one of them? Yours should have the uppercase F. From what I can tell by your edit, it reads as `function(validateform)` while it should be `function(validateForm)` - might be why, not 100% but I know that function names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to: *"How can I create a simple php mail form that will always work?"*

There are many PHP based forms that can be found on the Web, and you will find many by Googling "php form with validation", for example. Make sure that it includes proper validation and sanitization.

- [**Here is one example on tutsplus.com**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/)

Also consult [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) on PHP.net and [here also](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) for examples.

PHP(.net) has a function called `mail()` which you can read up on. [**Click here to see it.**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

- **Ajax** is another good method to use for email/forms. [**Here is one example.**](http://codular.com/php-jquery-contact-form)

Google "ajax email form" and you will get many hits.

---